# IBus icon is missing at startup?

Tags: icons, startup, ibus

After some installing, tweaking, ... the IBus icon is missing at startup, although it's working fine:

```
$ ps -ef | grep [i]bus
quanta    1918  1890  0 09:54 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --xim
quanta    1946  1918  0 09:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ibus/ibus-gconf
quanta    1948  1918  0 09:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/ibus/ui/gtk/main.py
quanta    1951     1  0 09:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
quanta    1987  1918  0 09:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/ibus-unikey/ibus-engine-unikey --ibus
```

I can make it appear by restarting the `ibus-daemon`:

```
$ ibus-daemon -x -r -d
```

I also have tried to add the IBus to the System tray whitelist but nothing changes.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have switched from Gentoo to Ubuntu. The culprit is: on Gentoo, IBus is started automatically by adding a line like `ibus-daemon -x -d` into the `~/.bashrc` which has appended to the end of the Ubuntu's `~/.bashrc`. Problem solved after deleting that line.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that doesn't solve my problem completely. After restarting one more time, it disappeared again.

Here're the steps that I have done to answer my own question: Who is starting IBus at startup?

Find out the parent of IBus:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ibu[s]
quanta    1922  1894  0 10:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --xim
quanta    1953  1922  0 10:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ibus/ibus-gconf
quanta    1955  1922  0 10:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/ibus/ui/gtk/main.py
quanta    1957     1  0 10:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
quanta    1983  1922  0 10:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/ibus-unikey/ibus-engine-unikey --ibus
```

Who has PID 1894:

```
$ ps -ef | awk '$2 == 1894 {print $0}'
quanta    1894  1563  0 10:43 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

Determine the startup script of IBus:

```
$ grep -lir ibus /etc/X11/
/etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/ibus
```

OK, open it up and change the `XIM_ARGS` to:

```
XIM_ARGS="--xim --replace --daemonize"
```

Restart to see if it works.